# Preciso deixar o meu gráfico em ordem decrescente!

Tags: r

o que estou usando é :

```
tabyl(situacao$situacao)
  ggplot(situacao, aes(x=situacao))+
    geom_bar(stat="count", width=0.7, fill="steelblue")+
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,size = 10))+
    scale_x_discrete(name ="Tipo de situação") +
    scale_y_continuous(name ="Adolescentes", breaks =seq(0,600,100))
    scale_y_continuous(name ="por adolescente")
```

Como deixo em ordem decrescente ?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score -1):

É sempre bom deixar um exemplo reproduzível para receber respostas adequadas. Como dito no comentário, sempre deixe um `dput` dos dados.

Para deixar um gráfico em ordem decrescente, você pode usar a função `reorder`. Como seu código não indica os dados que está usando, irei criar um código de exemplo.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(x, -x), y)) +
    geom_col()
```

[[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]